# Numerical computation of the spherical harmonic expansion coefficients

Tags: numerical-methods, spherical-harmonics

I'm trying to understand how to calculate numerically the spherical harmonic expansion's coefficients considering a specific set of points on the surface of a sphere.

It is well known that a function on the surface of a sphere $\mathbb R^{3}$ can be defined as an infinite sum of some constant coefficients $f_{m}^{l}$ and the spherical harmonics $Y_{m}^{l}(\Theta,\varphi)$ :

$$f(\Theta,\varphi)=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-l}^{l}f_{m}^{l}Y_{m}^{l}(\Theta,\varphi)$$

and that the constant coefficients $f_{m}^{l}$ can be calculated (similarly to the Fourier transform) as follow:

$$f_{m}^{l}=\oint_{\Omega}^{}f(\Theta,\varphi)Y_{m}^{l}(\Theta,\varphi)d\Omega$$

So my question is how to calculate these coefficients given a set of point on the sphere? In this thread [Integrating over particular grids to obtain Spherical Harmonic coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337806/integrating-over-particular-grids-to-obtain-spherical-harmonic-coefficients) they pointed out that the Gaussian quadrature is one solution but I am struggling to understand how to retrieve the coefficients $\omega$.

$$f_{m}^{l}=A\sum_{\Theta}^{}\sum_{\varphi}^{}f(\Theta,\varphi)Y_{m}^{l}(\Theta,\varphi)\omega(\Theta,\varphi)d\Omega$$

Does anyone have suggestions how to tackle the problem?

Comment: [Lebedev's quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebedev_quadrature) performs quite well for integration over a sphere. Also you can rewrite that a s an integral over $(\phi, \theta) \in [0, 2\pi] \times [0, \pi]$ and use nested gaussian quadrature